# Reducing Dimensions using PCA: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pca, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to implement an example project on DZone (https://dzone.com/articles/cv-r-cvs-retrieval-system-based-on-job-description) and running into a problem. In this case, I've set

```
dir_pca_we_EWE = 'pickle_model_pca.pkl'
```

And am executing the following:

```
def reduce_dimensions_WE(dir_we_EWE, dir_pca_we_EWE):
    m1 = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./wiki.en/GoogleNews.bin', binary=True)
    model1 = {}
    # normalize vectors
    for string in m1.wv.vocab:
        model1[string] = m1.wv[string] / np.linalg.norm(m1.wv[string])
    # reduce dimensionality
    pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=200)
    pca.fit(np.array(list(model1.values())))
    model1 = pca.transform(np.array(list(model1.values())))
    i = 0
    for key, value in model1.items():
        model1[key] = model1[i] / np.linalg.norm(model1[i])
        i = i + 1
    with open(dir_pca_we_EWE, 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(model1, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
return model1
```

This then produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 12, in reduce_dimensions_WE
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'items'
```

As always, all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're saving the PCA transform results into the `model1` variable. The `pca.transform` returns an `np.array` and not a `dict`.

Comment: Thanks Andreas and to datasailor below - how might I change the above code in order to have it successfully reduce the dimensions to 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by initializing `model1 = {}` as an empty dict. By using `transform` in

```
model1 = pca.transform(np.array(list(model1.values())))
```

the variable `model1` becomes a `numpy.ndarray`, which is the return type of the transform method of the pca. In the line

```
for key, value in model1.items():
    ...
```

you still use `model1` as if it is a dict, which it no longer is.

Comment: Just saw it after posting

Comment: Okay, it's fine. Just want to discourage stealing answers, as it might have seemed like :)

Comment: Thanks datasailor and to Andreas above - how might I change the above code in order to have it successfully reduce the dimensions to 200?

Comment: By the pca.transform method you already performed the reduction. The size of your transformed array is (n_samples, n_components).

Answer (score 0):

@datasailor answers your question and tells you what is wrong. In the comments you ask for how to reduce dimentions of data to 200, and I think the easiest way to do this would be using the `.fit_transform` from [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html), instead of the `.transform` as you are currently using:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=200)
lower_dim_Data=pca.fit_transform(data)
```